# mHttpClient.execute(httppost) with extremely long response 3g/4g.. but NOT wifi. after ICS update

Tags: android

I can't get this one.  Had an app that was working great.  Then I updated my Razr Droid to ICS and things have changed.

Running a Drupal Server with Drupal Services Module.  When I connect over wifi, everything works great.  When I connect over 3g/4g however, the httpclient.execute() method takes 3-4 minutes instead of seconds.  I put together the following sample code which recreates the problem. I should add that browser connection to the server over 4g works fine.. So I don't think this is a simple wireless connection issue.

```
public class DrupalTestActivity extends Activity {


    private Context mCtx;
public static long mSESSION_LIFETIME = 200000; // seconds.
final static String URL =   "www.myDrupalServer.com";
final static String ENDPOINT = "rest/";
String mResponse = null;
String cookie;
TextView textView;

public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        cookie = getCookie(mCtx);
        return cookie;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        textView.setText(mResponse);
    }



}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.mCtx = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    DoLogin task = new DoLogin();
    task.execute();
}


protected String getCookie(Context ctx) {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
    Long timestamp = settings.getLong("sessionid_timestamp", 0);
    Long currenttime = new Date().getTime() / 100;
    String cookie = settings.getString("cookie", null);
    if (cookie == null || (currenttime - timestamp) >= mSESSION_LIFETIME) {
        JSONObject mUserAccount = UserAccount.getJSONUserAccount(ctx);
        userLogin(mUserAccount);
        return getCookie(ctx);
    } else {
        Log.d("COOKIE", cookie);
        return cookie;
    }
}


public String userLogin(JSONObject mUserAccount) {
    String uri = URL + ENDPOINT + "user/login";
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    StringEntity se;
    try {
        HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams mHttpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(mHttpParams, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(mHttpParams, 10000);

        se = new StringEntity(mUserAccount.toString());
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json"));
        httppost.setEntity(se);
                    Log.d("STATUS", "CALLING DRUPAL");
        HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);
                    Log.d("STATUS", "LOGIN COMPLETE");
        mResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        // save the sessid and session_name
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mResponse);
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("cookie", obj.getString("session_name") + "="
                + obj.getString("sessid"));
        editor.putLong("sessionid_timestamp",
                new Date().getTime() / 100);
        editor.commit();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mResponse;
    }
}
```

Here is class UserAccount, but I don't really think it's relevant..

```
public class UserAccount {

    private String USER = "tester";
    private String PASSWORD = "passtest";
    private static Context mCtx;

    public UserAccount(Context Ctx, String Username, String Password) {
        mCtx = Ctx;
    }

    public void save(Context mCtx) {
        // TODO This would really work better if we just passed in the Account
        // Object
        Map<String, String> mMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mMap.put("username", USER);
        mMap.put("password", PASSWORD);
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        Iterator<?> iter = mMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
            editor.putString(mEntry.getKey().toString(), mEntry.getValue()
                    .toString());
        }
        editor.commit();
    }



    public static JSONObject getJSONUserAccount(Context ctx) {
        SharedPreferences accountSettings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        String nUsername = accountSettings.getString("username", "tester");
        String nPassword = accountSettings.getString("password", "dweeber");
        JSONObject JSONUser = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONUser.put("password", nPassword);
            JSONUser.put("username", nUsername);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return JSONUser;
    }

}
```

LogCat output for the wifi connection.

```
07-02 16:49:32.812: I/System.out(12001): debugger has settled (1401)
07-02 16:49:33.319: D/dalvikvm(12001): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
07-02 16:49:36.921: D/STATUS(12001): CALLING DRUPAL
07-02 16:49:37.749: D/libc(12001): Forward DNS query to netd(h=www.seinetest.com.php5-22.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com s=^)
07-02 16:49:43.046: D/STATUS(12001): LOGIN COMPLETE
```

Time is a dozen seconds or so..

LogCat output on 3g/4g

```
07-02 16:52:36.171: I/System.out(12759): debugger has settled (1362)
07-02 16:52:36.687: D/dalvikvm(12759): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
07-02 16:52:46.171: D/STATUS(12759): CALLING DRUPAL
07-02 16:52:47.265: D/libc(12759): Forward DNS query to netd(h=www.seinetest.com.php5-22.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com s=^)
07-02 16:53:17.569: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12759): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 16:53:17.593: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12759): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 16:54:38.593: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12759): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 16:54:38.616: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12759): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 16:56:08.921: D/STATUS(12759): LOGIN COMPLETE
```

MUCH longer login time!!

Clearly, the getExtractedText is something new,but is it a cause or a result?  I did a search on here for IInputConnectionWrapper getExtractedText and there is one question where someone asks what it's significance is.. It was closed and marked as a bad question. :(

Additional details are Verizon carrier
Server is hosted on Rackspace Cloud Servers
Phone Verizon Droid Razr, Android 4.0.4

I'm really hopeful I can get some guidance here or my months of work are bust.  Thanks a ton for any help at all.

Comment: Is this a repeated occurrence 9IE. every day for a week) or did you only test it recently within a short time period (IE. today for half hour). My point being, are you sure it's not just your phone's network connection? Could it be bad cell reception? If it worked earlier and isn't working now, with nothing being changed, it sounds more like a network issue than a coding one.

Comment: I did think of that but connecting to the server via my phone's browser over 3G/4G works great.

Comment: Also, there was a lot changed.  This all happened after ICS 4.0.4 update.  This is not a bad signal problem.  Also, my execute calls to google API are working fine. So it seems to be an issue between by phone and my server only in 3g.  Any ideas on even where to start on this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Your code looks fine, and it doesn't look like there'd be any issues with it. Have you tried it on another device to be sure?

Comment: No, I have not.  I am beginning to wonder if the problem is in fact a Verizon one.  The huge storms may have caused some issues with Verizon wireless between me and my servers.. I am going to give it a week or more and if it persists, I think the next issue to is get in touch with my host, and Verizon.  I should add, the same query works great to Google.. So it isn't a problem with ICS and my execute method.  It must be variable external forces I'm thinking.

Comment: Then again.. it just doesn't make sense.  The connection to the front end of the server is blazing fast.  my execute calls to google are blazing fast.  The problem must lie at the drupal interface, or something ICS is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I THINK I finally figured this out.  I did some research and some tests.
Phone Droid Razr, ICS 4.0.4 Verizone wireless.

I polled three of my servers and google.  All of my test servers are located on same cloud (RackSpace)
Response times were as follows.
Google: 42ms
My Server #1 100ms
My Server #2 96
My Server #3 - A test server with no Domain name registered running as www.seinetest.blah.blah.websitetestlink.com.  Rackspace automatically does this until a domain name is registered with the server.. Response time 14445 ms.

Desktop Browser times to all four sites were unremarkable.  So the problem HAD to be in the phone.. or did it?

After upgrade to ICS, this huge discrepancy in response times cropped up.  I did find some data in the above links that other phones were having problems with ICS getting through proxies.  I called Rackspace and the assured me the only difference between my registered domain name servers and server #3, was where the DNS pointers were pointing.. no proxies!

Leaving very little else to try, I registered server #3 with a domain name and WALLAH!
Response times from the ICS phone are equal to the other servers with registered domain names.. given that this all happened with the ICS upgrade I am inclined to think this is an ICS bug which I'll be reporting.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed any code, and this happened after upgrading from Gingerbread, you might really want to consider testing on a non-ICS device. Since Ice Cream Sandwich added "efficient network usage" capability, there has been some really random connection issues over wifi/3G/4G. You can see a lot of these type of issues on Google Code ( http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=3g+ics&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles ) and something a bit more tangent here: http://androidcommunity.com/signal-issues-arrive-after-android-4-0-4-ice-cream-sandwich-update-20120405/ 
Anyway, very strange, but reminiscent of a problem I saw with an unrelated device jumping to ICS.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the links!  I actually just got off the phone with Verizon and they do say they are having on going 3g/4g issues after the big storm that went through the midwest.. maybe that is it, but it seems like it should be a lot easier to get a string of JSON than an entire webppage that loads just fine.  I can't imagine also that I am the only one with this issue, but I have yet to find similar problems.  I need to get a non ICS phone to use, and read these links you posted.  Again, thank you.

Comment: I'm putting together a very long test and will see if this related to the network, or ICS.. or both?  I'll post results when I get them.

Comment: Great tracking on the proxy issue covered in your post below. Nothing more satisfying than nailing a ghost in the machine.